# For iOS, how to make "Any iOS SDK" work with code signing identity of Distribution?

Tags: iphone, ios, code-signing

For hours I am trying to make the code work with Distribution code signing in order to upload the `.app` to App Store (as a `.zip`).

It seems that in the "Build Settings" tab, if "Any iOS SDK" is set to Developer, then it works on the physical iPhone 4S device, just giving a warning of

```
warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, 
  contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an 
  iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)
```

but at least it runs on the real iPhone 4S.  If the "Any iOS SDK" is set to Distribution, then it now goes to Organizer and says:

```
A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found
```

But I already went to the Apple Developer website, created the Distribution certificate for App Store, and added to the keychain, and added to Organizer, and also right clicked on the iPhone 4S in Organizer and chose "Add Device to Provisioning Portal".

I even tried restarting Xcode, and restarting the whole machine, and it is the same thing.

Is there a way to solve this?  It seems the issue is with code signing "Any iOS SDK" but not my code.  (Xcode 4.3 is being used on Lion).

Maybe if only there is a button that will download the certificate for you, add it, and tell you what setting is set to Distribution in the Build Settings tab, and make the `.app`, zip it and upload it, then developers won't be spending hours or even 2, 3 days just to make it work.

Comment: please refer [A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found for debug mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167466/a-valid-provisioning-profile-for-this-executable-was-not-found-for-debug-mode)

Comment: Just to check, have you selected the provisioning profile from build setting of the product?

Answer (score 0):

See this post. I'd edit the Xcode project and remove the "Any iOS SDK" settings. It's buggy in my experience.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13627750/276626